# how to find fourier coefficients in matlab using approximate amount?

Tags: matlab

i have this formula to find fourier series in matlab

> f(n)= (f(t),exp(jnt))
>
> and the inner product is: =(1\2*pi)*integral((between pi and
>   -pi)*(f1*f2'*dt))

now i want to find fourier coefficients in matlab for this vector`(f(t)=t)`
where t is a vector that it's lenght is 1000.

i need to find the 2k+1  fourier coefficients by approximate amount when k=2 , which means `n=(-2,-1,0,1,2)` and then Compare it to the Analytical Calculation.

this is what i did so far:

```
clc

t = linspace(-pi,pi,1000);
f=t;
plot(t,f); hold all;


dt=2*pi/1000;
cnPlusVal=0;
cnMinusVal=0;
FourierS1=0;
FourierS2=0;
k=2;
for l = 1:k
    cnPlusVal=cnPlusVal+f.*exp(-i*l*t)*(dt/2*pi) ;
    cnMinusVal=cnMinusVal+f.*exp(i*l*t)*(dt/2*pi);

    FourierS1=FourierS1+cnPlusVal.*(exp(i*l*t));
    FourierS2=FourierS2+cnMinusVal.*(exp(i*-l*t));

end
```

now in order to Compare it to the Analytical Calculation i need to plot the forier series .. any help of how to do this in the same graph for f ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems to deal with here:

- your first plot is on a completely different scale when compared to the output series;
- you cannot infer a good axis scope using the limits of the series, because they contain complex numbers.

Here is the workaround I propose you:

```
figure();
plot(t,FourierS1);
x_lim = get(gca(),'XLim');
y_lim = get(gca(),'YLim');
hold on;
plot(t,f);
set(gca(),'XLim',x_lim,'YLim',y_lim);
hold off;
```

Basically:

1. you plot the Fourier serie;
2. you retain the current x-axis and y-axis limits of the plot;
3. you plot `f` over the current plot using the [hold](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) function properly;
4. you revert the plot limits to the previous scope.

Here is the output:

[image: Output]